# How do I deny page requests by REQUEST_METHOD?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a page that should only allow 'POST' headers but it currently accepts all.

This is the code I already have.

The echo displays the method used when testing with Postman, no matter what method I use I get a 200 OK result.

Do I need to add anything further into .htaccess or Apache config?

```php
// required headers
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

    echo ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To only allow `POST` request, you could add this into the htaccess file :

```
<LimitExcept POST HEAD>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

**Edit**

Or you could do it on the PHP script :

```
$currentRequestMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//A PHP array containing the methods that are allowed.
$allowedRequestMethods = array('POST', 'HEAD');

//Check to see if the current request method isn't allowed.
if(!in_array($currentRequestMethod, $allowedRequestMethods)){
    //Send a "405 Method Not Allowed" header to the client and kill the script
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 405 Method Not Allowed", true, 405);
    exit;
}
```

Reference : [PHP: Block POST requests](https://thisinterestsme.com/php-block-post-requests/)

Answer (score 0):

To check via PHP for allowed method and send out an individual error:

```php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] !== 'POST') {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    echo 'This method is not allowed!';
    exit;
}
// Here comes your regular code
```

Comment: This would work, but I would prefer to use the Headers, surely this is what they are for.

Comment: @PaulKnight these headers are CORS related, meaning they only apply when you make a request to a different origin using client-side JavaScript (like a cross-domain AJAX request.) If you want your Postman request to be denied based on that it used the POST method, then this is totally the wrong thing to begin with.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this.

Comment: @04FS, I am using this code from a different domain but am still getting the same responses.

```
xhttp.open("GET", "http://example.com/foo.php", true);
```

Comment: Of course you still get a 200 OK response - because your script is not sending a _different_ response. `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` determines whether the browser will consider the result of this request as valid for further processing, but it does not prevent the GET request from being attempted in the first place.

Comment: @04FS so how do I get this to work or what method should I be using?

Comment: See the other answer …?